# How to merge Pandas data frames with the same column names but different sequence?

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple Pandas Dataframes, all of them have the same column names but in different sequence for example:

```
   df_1:

    X   Y   Z   
    5   4   3   

   df_2:

    Z   X   Y
    5   4   4
```

How to merge them by column name?
I want my output look like this:

```
   df_3:

    X   Y   Z   
    5   4   3 
    4   4   5
```

Comment: `df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).reset_index(drop=True)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pandas.DataFrame.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html), it automatically takes care of `column` alignments:

```
>>> df.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
   X  Y  Z
0  5  4  3
1  4  4  5
```